# Python & Pandas: writing columns based on matches in different csvs

Tags: python, pandas, csv

New to Python and Pandas, any help or guidance appreciated.

I'm working with two different csv's, `roster.csv` and `assignment.csv`, with fields structured like so:

`roster.csv`:

```
first_name, last_name,  user_id,    user
John,   Doe,    0001,   abcd
Jane,   Doe,    0002,   efgh
John,   Smith,  0003,   ijkl
```

`assignment.csv`:

```
user,   text
abcd,   text1
efgh,   text2
ijkl,   text3
```

I'd like to use `roster.csv` to create new columns in `assignment.csv` when the `user` fields match, adding the `first_name`, `last_name`, and `user_id` fields. The output would look like:

```
user,   text,   first_name, last_name,  user_id
abcd,   text1,  John,   Doe,    0001
efgh,   text2,  Jane,   Doe,    0002
ijkl,   text3,  John,   Smith,  0003
```

So far I'm able to create an output that writes the headers for the fields above, but none of the data. Here's my working code thus far:

```
import pandas as pd

df_roster = pd.read_csv('roster.csv')
df_assignment = pd.read_csv('assignment.csv')

df3 = pd.concat([df_assignment, df_roster[~df_roster.user.isin(df_assignment.user)]])
```

Any insights on how to proceed? All assistance appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you use merge ?

Here is the guide for you.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

Answer (score 1):

Use `merge`, not `concat`, this ensures that the key will be aligned:

```
df_roster.merge(df_assignment, left_on='user_id', right_on='user')
```